# Double vertical line column type in tabular

Tags: tables, tabularx, arrays, columns, hline

I need a column type with 2 vertical lines but I want the horizontal line to not go trought it.

The result would be like this :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| p{5cm} | p{0.1cm} | p{5cm} |}
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
    \lipsum[1][1] & & \lipsum[1][1]  \\
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
    \lipsum[1][1] & & \lipsum[1][1]  \\
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But that way, I can't make the space smaller.

So, I've created this columntype :

```
\newcolumntype{D}{!{\vrule \hspace{0.1cm} \vrule}}
```

And this is the result :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{D}{!{\vrule \hspace{0.1cm} \vrule}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| p{5cm} D p{5cm} |}
    \hline
    \lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][1]  \\
    \hline
    \lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][1]  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have no idea how to create this new column type and code the fact that I was the horizontal line to be interruped ... And the `\cline` command is not helping here ..

Thanks for the answers and sorry by advance if this question has been already asked ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to achieve this by a combination of `cmidrule` with `NiceTabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|p{5cm}||p{5cm}|}
    \cmidrule(r{0.25em}){1-1} \cmidrule{2-2}
    \lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][1]  \\
    \cmidrule(r{0.25em}){1-1} \cmidrule{2-2}
    \lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][1]  \\
    \cmidrule(r{0.25em}){1-1} \cmidrule{2-2}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks !! This is very nice !! :)

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, it's better to wait for some time (maybe a day) before accepting an answer as it is quite common to get a better answer later.